Utilizing F# Fable Emit for passing Parameterized String API Key
I have had some success working with F# Fable JS Interop for integrating with various 3rd party libraries like SignalR and LocalForage.  However, I'm no expert, and just find myself learning here and there, and find myself stumped here in regards to trying to JS Interop with Stripe Elements.  I've got a wider set of aspects working, but it is all built upon initializing an instance of Stripe within my ViewModel (this instance needs loaded when the 'page' first loads, but is supposed to be re-used (and not reloaded) in successive renders).  It is all working correctly whenever I put in my key as a hard-code within the Emit attribute; however, I have not been able to get it such that I can correctly pass the key as a parameterized string.  I figured that somebody may have some more experience or awareness with this, and so I will just try to highlight the particular approach.  Any help is highly appreciated!
This all works correctly, when I call this and then use my IStripe instance within the ViewModel:
[<ImportDefault("@stripe/stripe-js")>]
[<Emit("Stripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx')")>]
let initialize () : IStripe = jsNative

If I keep ImportDefault it no longer works, so I shifted this to ImportAll which no longer brings that error, but if I do this it tells me that I'm passing an Object instead of a string:
[<ImportAll("@stripe/stripe-js")>]
[<Emit("Stripe($0)")>]
let initializeByKey (key: string) : IStripe = jsNative

Thus, I do the following, and I don't get the errors, but now it just get a 401 auth error from Stripe:
[<ImportAll("@stripe/stripe-js")>]
[<Emit("Stripe('$0')")>]
let initializeByKey (key: string) : IStripe = jsNative

This is the code that is calling the initializeByKey function:
let initViewModel () =
    { Stripe = StripeInstance.initializeByKey "pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx"
      CheckoutForm = init () }

This builds and runs correctly if I use the StripeInstance.initialize (), but not in this parameterized scenario. It seems like this is just something that I'm not doing correctly with the Emit attribute definition. I'm not really sure how to figure this out. I assume that somehow it is not passing the string correctly, or maybe adding the single-quote characters.
This has been resolved now, as per my answer below.  I'm just keeping this as a reference for anyone else that I would've found helpful when I was trying to search for what was wrong.

Got it working...!  If anyone has more insights to this, please add.  However, I needed to do the following:
[<ImportAll("@stripe/stripe-js")>]
[<Emit("Stripe($1)")>]
let initializeByKey (key: string) : IStripe = jsNative

As per my understanding:

It seems that the first parameter $0 was actually a Stripe.JS Object being imported and NOT the key string parameter.
$1 was taking the string I was passing in, and I needed to remove the single quotes as this was already being passed in as a string!

